# How to generate a jQuery snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to generate a simple jQuery code snippet in JavaScript and append it to one of the divs already available in my html file. Here is the string I am trying to append as an html content of the existing div element in my html file:

```
<form><div id=\"radio\"><input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio1\" name=\"radio\" /><label 
for=\"radio1\">Choice 1</label><input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio2\" name=\"radio\" /><label 
for=\"radio2\">Choice 2</label><input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio3\" name=\"radio\" /><label 
for=\"radio3\">Choice 3</label></div></form>
```

If you try the following code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E2zTn/6/):

```
$('div#new').append('<form><div id=\"radio\"><input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio1\" name=\"radio\" /><label 
for=\"radio1\">Choice 1</label><input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio2\" name=\"radio\" /><label 
for=\"radio2\">Choice 2</label><input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio3\" name=\"radio\" /><label 
for=\"radio3\">Choice 3</label></div></form>')
```

The Radio elements are displayed but with no jQuery visual style. When trying the same string in a static html file (see below) the visual style appears correctly. Would appreciate your help.

PS: I am trying to avoid jquery\html\JS template so would be great it I could get this code working with no needs of templates.

Thanks,
Jamil

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div id="radio">
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" />
            <label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>

            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" />
            <label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>

            <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" />
            <label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"but with no jQuery visual style"_ - What does that mean? The jsfiddle you linked to doesn't have any styles except the one for the "TEST" heading. Can you do a jsfiddle with the desired result? (By the way, you don't need to escape all the double-quotes when the string is quoted with singles.)

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan. I mean that I get plain radio buttons rather than the fancy jQuery visual see [this picture](http://jquerymobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/jquery-mobile-check-radios.png) (see pet choices) here is the code working JSFiddle (thanks to netbrain's answer below), here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/E2zTn/10/). I still can't get it working when creating an html page and adding the following function '$(window).load(function() { $('div#new').append('<the code>'); });' . Not sure what am I doing wrong in the html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.trigger('create') on the element will force the element to re-render again picking up all necessary styles.

Answer (score 1):

seems to work just fine...

http://jsfiddle.net/E2zTn/10/

All i did was add

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

....

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @netbrain, JSFiddle is showing it correctly now. Do you mind letting me know whats going wrong in the html file containing the JS function trying to do the same as JSFiddle? here is the function I am trying to use in the html. `$(window).load(function() {
                $('div#new').append('<the code>');
            });` the result is un-styled radio buttons

Comment: I have the exact head content as the one in your previous comment (+ the load function for creating adding the radio buttons)

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle with your exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand from your code what you're trying to do as it doesn't entirely match your description, but have you tried something like:

```
$("#radio").append('<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label 
for="radio1">Choice 1</label><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" /><label 
for="radio2">Choice 2</label><input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label 
for="radio3">Choice 3</label>');
```

The difference is that rather than adding stuff outside `#radio` you are adding it inside instead. Does that help?

Thanks! Neil

Comment: Thanks @NeilSHamilton . To explain what I am trying to do: I want to add a radio element from Javascipt rather than having it statically defined in the html code. And you suggestion won't fit as I need the complete radio group to be greated\appended dynamically not just the options